# React dynamic page render by api response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dynamic-import

I have an api that returns JSON with object array {component_name: string, component_data: any}. Based on this response render react page using function with switch-case by component_name and pass data to component in this case. I have many componets and this switch is very large. Can it be solved differently?

code snippet eg.

```
import Header from "./Header";
import Link from "./Link";
import Image from "./Image";

const pageComponents = (pageJson) => pageJson.map(p => {
  switch(p.component_name) {
     case: 'header': {
       return <Header content={p.component_data.text} />

     case: 'link': {
       return <Link content={p.component_data.text} href={p.component_data.src} />

     case: 'image': {
       return <Image src={p.component_data.src} alt={p.component_data.alt} />

     }
   }
});



const EgPage = () => {

const pageJSON = [
 {component_name: 'header', component_data: {text: 'Heder text 1'}},
 {component_name: 'link', component_data: {text: 'Heder text 2', src: 'www.test.com'}},
 {component_name: 'image', component_data: {src: 'www.test.img/1.jpg', alt: 'Test img'},
 {component_name: 'header', component_data: {text: 'Heder text 2'},
]

return <div>{pageComponents(pageJSON)}</div>
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should bother about this switch case, because you have fixed number of components and there will be no need for scaling.

However if you have this switch in multiple places in the application, then you have to create a wrapper component, that will encapsulate this switch case, so it's not duplicated.